# How can I get my Dwarves to use wheelbarrows to haul building material?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm building a stone structure far away from my stone stockpile. When the dwarves are hauling stone to the structure, they get incredibly slow. How can I get them to use wheelbarrows to haul this material to the building being built?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make a small second stone stockpile very close to your building site. Set it to take from links only and then link it to your main stone stockpile. Assign several wheelbarrows to the small stockpile so your dwarves haul stones to it faster. Your dwarves should efficiently fill the small stockpile with stones and then inefficiently haul stones from it to your building site. Since it is so close, the inefficient hauling should not effect building time much.

If this isn't fast enough for you, the dfhack mod has an autodump command that will transport any objects designated as dumped to wherever your cursor is. You can use this to place any stone needed right next to your building site.

Comment: If you use the autodump cheat, don't forget to claim (d-b-c) the stones else they won't get used.